# Unix ksh - To print the PID number and repeat count

Tags: shell, sorting, unix, grep, ksh

Log file abc.log

```
PID:6543 ……    
…………………
PID:4325 ……
……………………
PID:6543 ……
```

Log file xyz.log

```
PID:8888 ……
…………………
PID:9992 ……
……………………
PID:6543 ……
```

Note: The PID numbers can repeat in a file. And also one PID number can appear in multiple log files.

This question is asked in an interview today that I have to return output with each PID number and the count of each PID number logged today.
Here is the script that I have written. Can you confirm if that would work or not. The interviewer didn't said if my answer is correct or not. Can someone review this for me. They want me to print each unique PID:number and its count with tab space like PID:5674 10

— If today’s and previous day’s log files are in same folder

```
#!/bin/ksh

cd /A/B/ 
for a in `ls -lrt | grep "Mar 24" | awk '{print $9}'`;    — list of files generated today
do 
grep "^PID:" $a | cut -d " " f1  >> /tmp/abc.log   — saving first column which look like PID:23456 
done

for b in `cat /tmp/abc.log | sort -u`;
do
x=grep $b /tmp/abc.log | grep -v grep | wc;
echo $b"    "$x    — will print like PID:23456  56(count)
done
```

```
#!/bin/ksh

— If today’s log files are in different folder
cd /A/B/
for a in `ls /A/B/*.log`
do
grep "^PID:" $a | cut -d " " f1 >> /tmp/abc.log
done

for b in `cat /tmp/abc.log | sort -u`;
do
x=grep $b /tmp/abc.log | grep -v grep | wc;
echo $b"    "$x
done
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: They want me to print each unique PID:number and its count with tab space like ..  PID:5674    10

Comment: There's a ton of UTF-8 curly quotes in your scripts that should be ASCII double quotes `"`. As is, these scripts cannot be tested easily by anyone.

Comment: corrected now. Looks like they converted to UTF-8 while pasting from a text file to the web page.

Comment: You can try something like `grep -Eo "PID:[0-9]*" | sort | uniq -c` and use `sed` to change the format to the required one. A `grep` inside a loop (for each line) should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk`

```
grep -h 'PID:' *.log > all_pids.log  
#put only PID lines to a file.This can also be done 
#with pattern in awk and multiple files. I'm just separating it for clarity

awk  '
  { a[$1]++ }     #increments by 1 for corresponding PID
  END {
    for (i in a) {
      printf "%s %s\n", i, a[i];   
    }
  }
'  all_pids.log
```